# Scraping Script Not Working Properly On Heroku, But Works On VsCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a simple products scraping app, When I Start The Server On VsCode It Works Fine, But On Heroku It Only Scrapes The First Product And Blocks There, Please See The Photos, I'm Open To Any Suggestions.

[image of it working on vsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb5Og.png)

[image of it working on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT3Q7.png)

Note: I had the same problem on vs code before (the same project) and solved it but it's not working on heroku. The problem was that an await never returns anything it just blocks the code so the server stays on that line forever.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont think the problem is in heroku, maybe you need to add catching errors in your application, and see what cases the trouble.

Comment: I actually have error handling implemented... After debugging I found out that when script line gets executed it hangs in there, And when implementing "timeout" it throws the error "time's up", What I'm guessing is that Heroku is preventing request to the domain I'm scraping... I've seen things like these a lot on heroku, for example they also prevent links with words like "contact" in theme... 

Do you know about any other Heroku alternative with an easy NodeJs apps deployment process ?

Comment: AWS, and firebase are alternatives i now about.